# How to delay before window.close() with addEventListener(webkitTransitionEnd)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, webkit-animation

I am not very well-versed in JS and could not understand how to apply similar answers to my question, so I would appreciate your help and advice.

---

**What I'm Making:**
I am working on a webview pop-up. It has a close button at the bottom that I want to be animated the same as the in-app buttons.

**How I'm Doing It:** 
I am currently closing it simply with `<a href="#" onclick="window.close(); return false;"><img class="button" src="img.png"></a>`.

I have a webkit animation that changes on `img.button:active` mode.

**My Issue:** 
I want the transition to complete before the window closes. I know that I must use `addEventListener` to check when the transition has ended, but I cannot seem to do this correctly with `window.close()`. Is there a good way to do this?

---

I have not been able to figure this out by myself reading tons of documentation all day.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is to add a class using [Element.classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) when the user click on the anchor or the image then add [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) on that given class.

```js
function closeWindow () {
    alert("actice: transition end you can call window.close() now");
    window.close();
}
function anchorActive (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    imgButton.classList.add("active")
}

  var clickAnchor = document.querySelector("#clickAnchor"),
      imgButton = document.querySelector("img.button");

  clickAnchor.addEventListener("click", anchorActive, false);
  imgButton.addEventListener("transitionend", closeWindow, false);
```

```css
img{
  opacity: 1; 
  transition: opacity 3s ease
}
img.active{opacity: .3}
```

```html
<a id=clickAnchor href="#"><img class="button" src="http://placehold.it/150x150.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the event `transitionend` that is triggered on the element `img.button`, which signals the end of a CSS transition. However, since browser support for `transitionend` is patchy (although all latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari support `transitionend` natively without vendor prefixes), you should [use this script](https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/) to sniff out which event is actually supported.

With regards to the markup, I strongly suggest avoiding inline JS but set up an event listener instead.

```
<a href="#" id="closeWindow"><img class="button" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a>
```

My script also assumes that there might be multiple `img.btn` elements on the page, so we have got to loop through all elements that match the selector. If that is not the case, you can simply use `document.querySelector` and forgo the loop.

```
// Determine which transntionend event is supported
function whichTransitionEvent() {
    var t,
        el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

    var transitions = {
        "transition"      : "transitionend",
        "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
        "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
        "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
    }

    for (t in transitions){
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}
var customTransitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();

// Get button
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('img.btn:active'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; ++i) {
    btns[i].addEventListener(customTransitionEnd, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Transition End');
        // window.close();
    });
}
```